# java-why new() slower than newInstance()

Tags: java, reflection

i know that if i create new objects with reflection,it is very slow ,so i test it.but the result makes  me puzzled，**newInstance**() is faster than **new()**,my jdk version is **java version "1.8.0_77"**.

```
public class Test {

static class B {
}

public static long timeDiff(long old) {
    return System.nanoTime() - old;
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    int numTrials = 10000000;
    B[] bees1 = new B[numTrials];
    Class<B> c = B.class;
    long nanos;
    nanos = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < numTrials; i++) {
        bees1[i] = new B();
    }
    System.out.println("Normal instaniation took: " + TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(timeDiff(nanos)) + "ms");
    B[] bees2 = new B[numTrials];
    nanos = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < numTrials; i++) {
        bees2[i] = c.newInstance();
    }
    System.out.println("Reflecting instantiation took:" + TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(timeDiff(nanos)) + "ms");

}
```

}

the result:

- Normal instaniation took: 2363ms
- Reflecting instantiation took:1679ms.

so i don't know why..who can explain it ?

Comment: Your results are not meaningful, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Comment: Try swapping the tests, in other words do reflection then normal. My guess is that the first load of `new B()` takes the longest. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java